# Server Error after Decompiling ASP.NET Application

Tags: asp.net, decompiling

I am getting the following error after decompiling ASP.net Website.
PLEASE HELP.

Could not load file or assembly 'Pirates.EmpTix.UI.Web.EComps' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Pirates.EmpTix.UI.Web.EComps' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

[image]

Comment: you have a missing reference to Pirates.EmpTix.UI.Web.EComps. Is that a DLL or project which should be part of your solution?

Comment: yes Its the project, and I already add it in current solution also reference it using respective namespace.

Comment: by the way did you mean decompiling or compiling?

Comment: Decompiling:- Way to generating the application code from DLL's.    Compiling:- way to generating DLLs from the application code.

Comment: so you are trying to generate the application code from the DLL?

Comment: Yes, Because I lost the whole folder of the projects.

Comment: you should use backups, or a version control server :-) But anyway, what tool did you use to do the decompile?

Comment: telerik JustDecompile.

Comment: It's not something I have experience with, but I would guess that either it didn't extract everything properly from the DLL, or it is still expecting a compiled DLL instead of source code. Depends how your solution's structured. Is Pirates.EmpTix.UI.Web.EComps a single project, or maybe a single class? Also, have you emptied and rebuilt your solution completely before running it again?

Comment: "System.IO.FileNotFoundException" error mean you are missing file. Most obviously .dll library from compiled folder. Check that corresponding project configured to output compiled .dll into same directory as main project.